# Software to cloak IP/data while browsing

Tags: windows, web-browser, privacy

I'm looking for software or a plugin that is compatible with Google Chrome or Firefox that works in conjunction with Chrome's Incognito mode or Firefox's InPrivate browsing mode so the following is done.

- Encrypts data to and from proxy.
- Doesn't save cookies, temporary files, etc. (I believe Chrome already does this to some degree).
- Able to turn the service off and on with a touch of a button.
- No subscription or monthly fees.
- Relatively quick data transfer speeds.

Comment: Any plugin that lets you manage proxies (or even Firefox itself in its Network options, though that only lets you manage one proxy at a time) will suffice here on the software front. Your question seems to be asking for a proxy *service* meeting these criteria. I would wager that asking for a proxy service that respects your privacy is off-topic for this site, since you're asking about a web service that is trustworthy, rather than about a piece of software. Remember that any IP cloaking or proxying requires someone to have a physical box set up somewhere else to offer that to you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think [Tor's browser](https://www.torproject.org/) could be what you're looking for. You can read [their overview](https://www.torproject.org/about/overview.html) for details on how it works, but basically you use a specialized version of Firefox that goes through the Tor network, keeping you anonymous.

Comment: Tor does not keep you anonymous. The US Government / FBI recently executed an attack upon the network that allowed them to identify users. It's better than a lot of things, but it's not a guarantee.

Comment: Could you add some more information about this here? Having a link is nice, but having the info here on site makes it easier to search and find it. Also, could you add a screenshot of it?